# babel/register not running on server

Tags: javascript, docker, ecmascript-6, strongloop, babeljs

I’m using babel/register in a project. My index.js looks something like `require(‘babel/register’); require(‘./server’);` and my server.js starts using ES6. Running this on my local machine is fine. However, when I push it to the staging server, I get an error implying that the transformation from 6 to 5 is not taking place:

> 2015-10-19T09:16:32.625Z pid:53 worker:11 /home/strong-pm/svc/2/work/.../server.js:1
>
> 2015-10-19T09:16:32.628Z pid:53 worker:11 (function (exports, require, module, __filename __dirname) { import dotenv fr
>
> 2015-10-19T09:16:32.628Z pid:53 worker:11                                                            ^^^^^^
>
> 2015-10-19T09:16:32.628Z pid:53 worker:11 SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

As you can possibly see, I’m using strong-pm to deploy through docker if that affects the situation at all.

Do you know why this would work on my local but not on staging?

Answer (score 2):

This was the fault of `strong-pm` which, as of posting, ignores your `main` in your package.json, and instead looks at `scripts.start`. Whodathunkit.

Comment: Please could you add _how_ to fix the problem, not just _why_ it occurs.